# NSDate calculation missing 1 hour when date set manually from settings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a strange query...

If the date/time is set automatically in my iPhone than the time is correctly displayed as seen below... [image]

And if the date/time is set manually with a different time zone than I am actually in (**I am in India and set it to London. Works fine if set to India**),it shows wrong results only for two dates calculated by using the method `[self.surveyModel.creationDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*30]` and similarly for 20 days .. see image below..

[image]

I am not setting the default time zone or local time zone for the application, and I am suing the following method to show the result...

```
- (NSString *)stringWithFormat:(NSString *)format {
    NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [outputFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    [outputFormatter setDateFormat:format];
    NSString *timestamp_str = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:self];
    [outputFormatter release];
    return timestamp_str;
}
```

what am I doing wrong here...?

Comment: Just a thought, not sure if it is correct or not. Did you take Daylight Saving into account? when dealing with manual date you need to look into that.

Comment: I think @Steven is right.  You should break the dates into components and add days instead of TimeInterval.

Comment: @Steven thanks for your inputs.. you were correct. I was not including the day light savings. YOu can post your comment as an answer and I will accept it./

Comment: posted an answer for you. and glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** This answer is in reply to the Comment on the Question

It seem the error is caused by regions with Daylight Savings, in this case London, England.

When the date/time is calculated automatically, the iOS DateTime library takes the DayLight Saving into account.

When dealing with the DateTime manually, which you are doing through this code `[self.surveyModel.creationDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*30]`

You are setting the DateTime without listing the DayLight option enabled. So when you take the `NSTimeZone` look for the DayLight savings options.